# LInux vs BSD for kernel development

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel

I recently updated my rusty C skills, and I've been trying to find a project to try them out on, so I picked kernel development (after all, C is a systems language). So, I was wondering which would be easier to start out with, Linux or one of the BSDs? Linux has a larger userbase (so I would probably have more support), but it also has a humongous codebase (9 million lines last time I checked), would the BSDs be easier to start out with because they combine the userbase and kernel into one large codebase? Also, is it best to just start reading the kernel source code? And, are they trying to implement new features aside from SMP and new drivers?

Comment: why the vote down? I thought the question was pretty specific.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am using and developing for Linux for many years, but am lacking any real experience with BSD to recommend either way.

You sound lacking experience for kernel hacking. Just reading kernel source might be insightful, but won't really teach you much. There is a lot going on in Linux kernel besides drivers. For example, latest 2.6.38 was focused on desktop responsiveness. DRM stack is ever changing and could use more man power.
I'd suggest start easy, small fixes for beta drivers, etc.

Comment: When you say I lack experience, do you mean with kernel hacking or with C and programming in general?

Comment: I don't know about your C skills and how familiar you are with linux. I was talking about the linux kernel, and kernel hacking and programming. Nonetheless, there are resources about linux kernel hacking, just search the web, it should get you started.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, I can only speak of Linux kernel hacking for myself. Currently I'm in an internship where I am working on a kernel, and I never did this before. But I was able to learn a lot of stuff in a quite short time, due to several reasons (again, I want to point out that I don't know how much of this is covered withint he BSD community):

- Tutorials. The Linux Community is quite big and therefore you will find a lot of beginners information on kernel hacking. I feel like the standard to begin with was [this guide](http://tldp.org/LDP/lkmpg/2.6/html/lkmpg.html). If you read it you will see, that even kernel hacking starts with hello world ;)
- [Linux Cross Reference](http://lxr.linux.no/+trees). A great tool. It covers the complete Vanilla source code and shows you where each function/struct/define/whatever was defined and implemented, so no long searching for some stuff
- The modular build of linux (I assume the same goes for BSD) Clearly you won't be able to look through 9 mio lines of code. But you can start easy with a little loadable kernel module and then go deeper. Maybe look at other modules first, hack them, and finally dig into the directly compiled stuff
- The sheer community size. Not only kernel mailing lists, but also a huge number of forums or Q&A sites like this one where you can be sure to get help if you don't know what to do ;)

Just my 2 cents ;)